# SQL Server Management Studio SELECT TOP(119) vs SELECT TOP(120)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've noticed that there's a significant performance drop if I move from `SELECT TOP(119)` to `SELECT TOP(120)`.  Does anyone know why this could be the case?

FYI, I'm querying a single View which joins two tables: one with 2.2m rows x 150 cols and the other with 1.0m rows and 10 cols.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the execution plan for the queries. The query optimizer uses statistics to try to figure out the best way to fetch the rows you need and for you it looks like you have found the spot where the optimizer choose to use a different plan.